# How to solve encoding problem in pyspark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, encoding

I have .csv file like this:

```
پالايش  صندوق پالايشي يکم-سهام  157053  82845166    8.62981E+12 100140  100010  105180  5040    5.03    104170  4030    4.02    100000  108000  1399-9-23
                                                            
شستا    سرمايه گذاري تامين اجتماعي  82830   172058561   4.80766E+12 28880   28100   27700   -1180   -4.09   27940   -940    -3.25   27580   28480   1399-9-23
```

Now when I want read this file with pyspark:

```
df = spark.read.option("inferSchema","true").option("encoding", "utf-8").csv("1399-12-27.csv").toDF( 'simbol',
    'name',
     'count',
     'volume',
     'Value',
     'lastday',
     'first',
     'lastTransactionamount',
     'lastTransactionChange',
     'lastTransactionPercentage',
     'finalpriceamount',
     'finalpriceChange',
     'finalpricePercentage',
     'min',
     'max',
     'date')
df.show(5)
```

It is shown as follows:
[image]

please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: please provide source data in text format, not as images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite possible here that your encoding gets bypassed and not working. Try using any of the aliases as "utf8, latin-1, latin1, iso-8859-1, iso8859-1" instead of "utf-8".

See the related docs as : "https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings"

For example replace: option("encoding", "utf-8") with ("encoding","iso-8859-1")

Comment: I test  " latin-1, latin1, iso-8859-1, iso8859-1" instead of "utf-8". but don't work. it is one of results: ÇáÇíÔ|ÕäÏæÞ ÇáÇíÔí íã...

Comment: thanks. it works. I see "https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings" and "windows-1256" is answer. thanks a lot